# Why do I see MOV Rn, Rn instructions in debugging-mode nVIDIA SASS code?

Tags: assembly, cuda, mov, nvidia-sass

Here's a snippet of some SASS code for a kernel I'm working on (for an sm52 target, [compiled in debugging mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20127430/1593077)):

```
/*0028*/                   ISETP.GE.U32.AND P0, PT, R1, R0, PT;    /* 0x5b6c038000070107 */
/*0030*/               @P0 BRA 0x40;                               /* 0xe24000000080000f */
/*0038*/                   BPT.TRAP 0x1;                           /* 0xe3a00000001000c0 */
                                                                   /* 0x007fbc0321e01fef */
/*0048*/                   IADD R2, R1, RZ;                        /* 0x5c1000000ff70102 */
/*0050*/                   I2I.U32.U32 R2, R2;                     /* 0x5ce0000000270a02 */
/*0058*/                   MOV R2, R2;                             /* 0x5c98078000270002 */
                                                                   /* 0x007fbc03fde01fef */
/*0068*/                   MOV R3, RZ;                             /* 0x5c9807800ff70003 */
/*0070*/                   MOV R2, R2;                             /* 0x5c98078000270002 */
/*0078*/                   MOV R3, R3;                             /* 0x5c98078000370003 */
                                                                   /* 0x007fbc03fde01fef */
/*0088*/                   MOV R4, R2;                             /* 0x5c98078000270004 */
/*0090*/                   MOV R5, R3;                             /* 0x5c98078000370005 */
/*0098*/                   MOV R2, c[0x0][0x4];                    /* 0x4c98078000170002 */
                                                                   /* 0x007fbc03fde01fef */
/*00a8*/                   MOV R3, RZ;                             /* 0x5c9807800ff70003 */
/*00b0*/                   LOP.OR R2, R4, R2;                      /* 0x5c47020000270402 */
/*00b8*/                   LOP.OR R3, R5, R3;                      /* 0x5c47020000370503 */
```

I'm noticing more than a couple of instructions of the form "Move the contents of register Rn to register Rn" - and that doesn't seen to make sense. I know that when compiling without debugging info enabled, and with optimizations, I don't get these instructions. But, even in debugging mode - why are they there? What's their purpose? AFAIK, when compiling CPU code for debugging you don't get these kind of instructions.

Comment: This code was clearly compiled for debugging

Comment: @talonmies: But why are these instructions useful/relevant in debugging mode?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that. All I know is the phenomenology - compile to debug without optimisation and you get code like that. Turn on optimisation and you get something more sane.

Comment: @talonmies: See edit. Making this question strictly about when you know it's in debugging mode.

Comment: Awesome, so you ask a question - which is answered, then decide you didn't like the answer you got, so you change the question....

Comment: @talonmies: No, I ask a question which is marked as duplicate, because you thought I wouldn't care about why these instructions are there if you said it's a compilation for debugging. SO tells me, and I quote "If this question is different, please edit it to explain how it is different", I do so, then I get flak.

Comment: As it's closed as duplicate, it's difficult to answer it in comment, comments are a bit short. Basically optimization of register allocations during compilation is optimizer step, not required to produce working binary. Most (all?) of the CUDA commands can be compiled separately (no context state is passed from command on to other one). So one of elementary compiler steps is to compile single command. That bare step has some sample how to compile it into independent piece of code, including fetch of value, modification, storing value, etc... and requires some registers - allocated randomly.

Comment: You certainly do get useless `mov` instructions in unoptimized code produced by compilers targeting x86.  Most of them are store/reloads between every statement, so that changing the value in the "permanent location" of a variable with a debugger produces an effect on the code, but you do see some reg-reg moves.  If it wasn't for all the store/reloading, you'd probably see more useless reg-reg moves.  Optimal register allocation is hard problem for compilers, and you sometimes see a useless `mov` instruction even in optimized code.

Comment: Then you have to bridge the commands together, so either the command does fetch everything from memory again, or when some value is left from previous command, it may reuse it. With random register allocation that often means you have to do `mov rn,rn` to get it into correct register for next command. If the register allocations are optimized during compilation, some registers may be allocated/shared between several commands, saving those "meaningless" `mov rn,rn` instruction. But that optimization is trivial for human, for fast debug build it's a bit too much work.

Comment: @PeterCordes great addition about intermediate stores supporting the debugging point of view, I completely missed that one. Now somebody with knowledge of CUDA compiler internals can probably build fully detailed answer, connecting all the dots.

Comment: @Ped7g: you might want to copy your comments into an answer, if you think they're worthy.  It doesn't have to be a great answer, but this sort of generic answer is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer you get that get strange code because you've turned on debugging which turns off optimization. This is normal with modern optimizing compilers because of how they work. They break down operations into a primitive [static single-assignment (SSA) form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) which makes it easier to optimize but when not optimizing generates worse code that more simpler non-optimizing compiler would.

There's also a possibility, though I don't think it's the case here, that the instructions are deliberately inserted NOPs in order delay execution. GPUs have instruction sets that are much much different than the general purpose CPUs that you may familiar with. For example most CPUs work as if instructions are executed one at a time and strictly in the order they're given. This is true despite the fact that modern CPUs will try to execute instructions in parallel and even out of order, for improved performance. GPUs typically don't work this way. If you try to use the result that a previous instruction stores in some register before that instruction is finished, you'll get the old value of the register. Unlike a CPU, a GPU won't automatically wait for the instruction to finish before executing the next instruction that depends on it.

If you look at the dissembled code you'll notice that instructions are grouped into bundles of three instructions. You might also see that there's hidden instructions between the bundles.  The machine code for the instruction is shown on the right (eg. `/* 0x007fbc0321e01fef */`), but its not disassembled on the left and its address isn't shown despite taking up an 8-byte slot like any other instruction. This actually a [scheduling block control code](https://github.com/NervanaSystems/maxas/wiki/Control-Codes). It's not a real instruction, but instead it instructs the GPU how it should schedule the instructions in the bundle before it. It tells the GPU things like which instructions need to wait for previous instructions to complete and how long they should wait.

Finally there's one more possibility, though extremely unlikely, that the redundant MOVs aren't actually NOPs at all. They could be acting on yet to overwritten register values and in parallel with other instructions in some weird manner that gives them a useful effect other than a delay. However this would be a very advanced optimization technique that I would only expect in hand-tuned assembly code, not in a compiler that isn't even generating optimized code.

Comment: Re the penultimate paragraph. I am skeptical that the fact that the GPU architectures from Kepler on use VLIW-like (or Itanium-like, if you will) instruction bundles has anything to do with the MOVs observed. I am pretty sure you get the same effect in debug builds for `sm_20`, which doesn't use instruction bundles.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last paragraph. AFAIK nVIDIA GPUs don't run multiple instructions in parallel for the same warp (the parallelization allows multiple warps to execute instructions in the same cycle). Also, even considering the instructions in a 'bundle' as parallel, you wouldn't have two instructions in a bundle writing to the same register - would you?

Comment: @njuffa I'm confident the bundles don't have anything to do with the redundant moves. There doesn't seem need to pad out bundles with NOPs like with the Itanium. The paragraph about control codes is just there to explain how the instructions are explicitly scheduled, given the apparent absence of anything in the disassembled code that does that.

Comment: @einpoklum If the GPU couldn't run instructions in parallel in a warp there wouldn't be any need for the scheduling codes. Each instruction would finish before the next one started execution so there would no need to explicitly delay an instruction in order to wait for an instruction that would otherwise run in parallel. Bundles aren't issued simultaneously, but it is possible to issue two consecutive instructions at the same time (at least on Maxwell) in certain circumstances. However, because of pipelining instructions will usually run in parallel despite not being issued in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Based on general compiler knowledge, I have no knowledge about CUDA.

Most of the programming languages have mostly context/state-less commands. Each such command can be compiled separately on it's own, into the target machine code/opcode output (making this compilation step sort of simple to implement, dealing only with single actually parsed command). Some exceptions are various *prefix*/*suffix*/*with* modifiers, or things like `continue`/`break` to control loops.

For example `variable = variable + 2;` can be compiled into "add two to variable" independently from previous and next command in the source (simple and fast), which turns into: "load variable from memory into register, add two to register, store value from register back to variable memory".

Which register will be used is difficult to decide. If you would think about it for a while, a random register allocation is just as good as any other naive allocation rule. That is often the way how registers are allocated at the early stage of compilation (using any register with smallest penalty for being clobbered).

But then you need some "bridge" code to connect commands between themselves, either using strictly variables in memory (having then no bridge code at all), or reusing/sharing some values between commands, just moving them into proper register (your "non sense" `mov rN,rN` instructions, saving some fetch instructions from memory).

Compilation stage(s) optimizing register allocations (trying to increase sharing/reusing of registers, reassigning registers for some commands and compiling them again, sometimes even reordering blocks of commands to make the register sharing more optimal) is non-trivial task and an time consuming compilation step, which is not required for the code to work. The debug compilation skips this step to produce binary faster.

Also in debug build it's desirable to store variable values into it's memory after each source command, to make results visible in debugger, although in optimized release build the compiler may recognize the "intermediary" nature of some results, and keeps them temporarily in registers only.

Comment: Actually modern optimizing compilers don't work that way. They break down statements and expressions in a primitive "static single-assignment" (SSA) form. This makes performing sophisticated optimizations easier, but typically results in the unoptimized code being worse than the simpler approach of directly converting high level language constructs into assembly.

Comment: What @RossRidge said. The SSA form mentioned is similar in function to the register renaming in processors. The result of every operation is assigned to a new virtual register. This can easily be seen in the PTX intermediate code used by CUDA both as compiler intermediate format and virtual ISA. The last paragraph of Ped7g's answer probably also applies. In order to report the value of each variable at any time, the debugger may require a variable to either reside in storage, or in a *particular* register, necessitating `MOV`s whenever that variable is needed elsewhere.